# How to get JSON response from submitJob operation?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-rest-api, geoprocessing-service

I'm trying to get the JSON response of the submitJob operation launched by a restful call: http:///submitJob.
I'm using Java7.

The response I'm getting is an HTML response, using the code below:

```
URL url = new URL("http://<gp-task-url>/submitJob");

HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
        .openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json"); 
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
```

Do you have any idea on how to retrieve a JSON response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end of your submit job url, simply append &f=json

That will return the response in json, which should give you the jobID and status.

Comment: Thank you for showinf me the way. the value to append is : ?f=pjson

Comment: f=pjson will give you "pretty" json, meaning line breaks and tabs, nice to read.  f=json will give you raw json, no line breaks or tabs.